# Android AsyncTask not calling onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When I call my AsyncTask, doInBackground is run but onPostExecute is never called afterwards. Eclipse is not complaining about `@Override`s or any of the parameters in the AsyncTask, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Calling AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncDataFetcher(this).execute(productInfoUrls);
```

`productInfoUrls` is a list of urls.

AsyncTask:

```
private static class AsyncDataFetcher extends AsyncTask<List<String>, Void, List<JSONObject>> {

    Context context;

    public AsyncDataFetcher(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<JSONObject> doInBackground(List<String>... urls) {
        List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        JSONParser json_parse = new JSONParser();
        for (int i = 0; i < urls[0].size(); i ++) {
            jsonList.add(json_parse.getJSONFromUrl(urls[0].get(i)));
        }
        return jsonList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<JSONObject> jsonList) {
        if(jsonList != null){
            productInfoParser.Parse(jsonList); 
            loaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you add some logging and check your logcat output to see what is happening.

Comment: well I was wrong about the `i ++` needing to be `i++` without the space.  Just made test app and works fine with the space.

Comment: Bad way. :(. This code takes a long time to do. Your jsonList is null.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added a log to check and it appears that jsonList is not null.

Comment: One suggestion, you can simply pass String ...args instead of List<String> ...args. As variable arguments will do same thing as that of List.

Comment: Did you solve this one? I'm having the same issue -- doInBackground() returns but onPostExecute() is never called.

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks appropriate in your async task structure, but what you are doing in `doInBackground` could take forever!  I suspect that your app is starting the `doInBackground` and never finishing it.

I would add some debug logs to see how the json getting is progressing.

```
@Override
protected List<JSONObject> doInBackground(List<String>... urls) {
    List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    JSONParser json_parse = new JSONParser();
    for (int i = 0; i < urls[0].size(); i ++) {
        jsonList.add(json_parse.getJSONFromUrl(urls[0].get(i)));
        Log.d(TAG, "added " + i);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "returning jsonList");
    return jsonList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I added the logs and an additional log to the beginning of `onPostExecute`. "returning jsonList" is logged, but the log at the beginning of `onPostExecute` is not displayed. 

It appears that `onPostExecute` is not called for some reason, despite `doInBackground` returning correctly?